# iOS handle multiple APN when App closed

Tags: ios, swift, apn

When my App is closed and I get multiple APNs and click on one of them I do only get the data of the APN I clicked on. All other Notifications disappear.

How do I get the data of the notifications I didn't click on?

I'm currently handling my notifications like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let type: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
    let setting = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: type, categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(setting)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
    if let remoteNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? NSDictionary{
        self.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: remoteNotification as [NSObject : AnyObject])
    }
    return true
}
```

and:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]){
    if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
        if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary {
            if let message = alert["message"] as? NSString {
                //handle push message
            }
        } else if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSString {
            //handle push message
        }
    }
}
```

Also: If I receive notifications and open the app by clicking on the app logo instead of clicking on the notifications, all notifications seem to disappear, too.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

their is no api to get APNs that were NOT delivered to your app.

**in general, APNs make NO delivery guarantees**

Comment: So there is no way to fetch all notifications, when my device already received them and I click on one of them? If so, the only solution for me would be to save every Push Notification in my backend and download it, if the user clicks on a notification. This seems kind of ineffective to me.. I have trouble believing that it isn't possible otherwise :(
I always thought the delivery guarantees where meant for the way from Apple to the device, not from device to the app?

Comment: I'm sorry but that's how it is. You could look into additional silent pushes. Maybe that'll work for. But notifications are mainly for the user

Comment: Sorry @Daij-Djan, this is not what 3k1 asked in the first place. I am having the same scenario, and are not looking for a APN api to get "not-delivered" notifications.   The notifications are there already.  I guess he marked the answer as correct just to be polite, but the problem is still not solved

Comment: This what he asked. Sorry about your issue. Things also haven’t changed in the yrs

Answer (score 0):

Working with Swift 4 (iOS 11)

You have to be aware of when your app becomes active:

(add this to your AppDelegate):

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    // whenever the app gets active state, check for unprocessed notifications

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    center.getDeliveredNotifications(completionHandler: { (notifications: [UNNotification]) in
        print("count", notifications.count)
        for notification in notifications {
            print(notification.request.content.body)
        }

            // after working out all the notifications, you can decide to get rid of all or some with this two methods:
            // removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers:)
            // removeAllDeliveredNotifications
    })
}
```

- For some reason Apple named "Pending" the local notifications, and "Delivered" to the remote ones, so you can handle both independently.